# COMO HACER VARIABLE REGEXP

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  CONCAT(per.apellido," ",per.nombre) AS alumno,per.dni as
dni,car.descripcion,per.correo , jor.descripcion as nombrej
FROM persona as per
INNER JOIN inscripcion as ins on ins.id_persona=per.id_persona
INNER JOIN jornada as jor ON jor.id_jornada=ins.id_jornada
INNER JOIN carrera as car ON car.id_carrera=per.id_carrera
where jor.id_jornada = 1 AND per.apellido regexp '^[a-i]'
ORDER BY per.apellido;
```

Buenas tardes a todos.

Necesito que los valores de la expresion regular en esta consulta puedan ser variables , intente usar variables en un SP y no funciona.

¿Por favor, alguien podria orientarme sobre como podria hacerlo ?

Gracias.

edicion1 : Se me olvido mencionar que trabajo con el motor Mysql Version 5.7.21

Comment: `SET @\`REGEXP\` := '^[a-i]'; SELECT 'altamirano' REGEXP @\`REGEXP\`;`. Un SP también es una opción que debería funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
SET  @a =  '^[a-i]' ;

SELECT  CONCAT(per.apellido," ",per.nombre) AS alumno,per.dni as
dni,car.descripcion,per.correo , jor.descripcion as nombrej
FROM persona as per
INNER JOIN inscripcion as ins on ins.id_persona=per.id_persona
INNER JOIN jornada as jor ON jor.id_jornada=ins.id_jornada
INNER JOIN carrera as car ON car.id_carrera=per.id_carrera
where jor.id_jornada = 1 AND per.apellido REGEXP @a  
ORDER BY per.apellido;
```

Saludos.